# Why can I not return a List<Foo> if asked for a List<IFoo>?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I understand that, if `S` is a child class of `T`, then a `List<S>` is **not** a child of `List<T>`. Fine. But interfaces have a different paradigm: if `Foo` implements `IFoo`, then why is a `List<Foo>` not (an example of) a `List<IFoo>`?

As there can be no actual class `IFoo`, does this mean that I would always have to cast each element of the list when exposing a `List<IFoo>`? Or is this simply bad design and I have to define my own collection class `ListOfIFoos` to be able to work with them? Neither seem reasonable to me...

What would be the best way of exposing such a list, given that I am trying to program to interfaces? I am currently tending towards actually storing my `List<Foo>` internally as a `List<IFoo>`.

Comment: To address the underlying issues of this question regarding the generalized problem of Type conversion in .NET, please see my answer to a related question at [How Can I Convert Types at Runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312858/how-can-i-convert-types-at-runtime/7942350#7942350)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `List<Foo>` is not a subclass if `List<IFoo>` because you cannot store an `MyOwnFoo` object in it, which also happens to be an `IFoo` implementation.  ([Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))

The idea of storing a `List<IFoo>` instead of a dedicated `List<Foo>` is OK.  If you need casting the list's contents to it's implementation type, this probably means your interface is not appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example of why you can't do it:

```
// Suppose we could do this...
public List<IDisposable> GetDisposables()
{
    return new List<MemoryStream>();
}

// Then we could do this
List<IDisposable> disposables = GetDisposables();
disposables.Add(new Form());
```

At that point a list which was created to hold MemoryStreams now has a Form in it. Bad!

So basically, this restriction is present to maintain type safety. In C# 4 and .NET 4.0 there will be *limited* support for this (it's called *variance*) but it still won't support this particular scenario, for exactly the reasons given above.

Comment: I really don't understand this.  The list was created to hold IDisposables, not MemoryStreams.  You could do the same kind of thing with a List<Stream>, and the compiler let you.  What's different about interfaces?

Comment: No, you couldn't do this with List<Stream>. Try returning a List<MemoryStream> as a List<Stream> - you'll see it fail.

Comment: I sure wish I'd saved the code I'd written this afternoon, because you're right, it doesn't compile, and it shouldn't.  I wonder what I was thinking.

Answer (score 8):

In your returning function, you have to make the list a list of interfaces, and when you create the object, make it as an object that implements it.  Like this:

> ```
> function List<IFoo> getList()
> {
>   List<IFoo> r = new List<IFoo>();
>   for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
>       r.Add(new Foo(i+15));
>
>   return r;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

**MASSIVE EDIT**
<s>You'll be able to do it with C# 4.0, but</s>  [thanks Jon]

You can get around it using [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx):

```
public List<IFoo> IFoos()
{
    var x = new List<Foo>(); //Foo implements IFoo
    /* .. */
    return x.ConvertAll<IFoo>(f => f); //thanks Marc
}
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood it, no you won't. A list can be neither co- nor contra- variant, since it allows both "in" and "out" usage.

Comment: You'd also need to qualify the destination type: return x.ConvertAll<IFoo>(f=>f);

Comment: There is an extension method in System.Linq so you can do
return x.Cast<IFoo>(); instead of return x.ConvertAll<IFoo>(f => f);

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that `List<Foo>` is a different type to `List<IFoo>`, in the same way that `DateTime` is different to `IPAddress`, for example.

However, the fact that you have `IFoo` implies that collections of `IFoo` are expected to contain at least two implementations of `IFoo` (`FooA`, `FooB`, etc...) because if you expect there to only ever be one implementation of `IFoo`, `Foo`, then the `IFoo` type is redundant.

So, if there is only ever going to be one derived type of an interface, forget the interface and save on the overhead. If there are two or more derived types of an interface then always use the interface type in collections/generic parameters.

If you find yourself writing thunking code then there's probably a design flaw somewhere.

Comment: There are other reasons for using interfaces than just if I am intending for there to be different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If, at the time that `IList<T>` was invented, Microsft had been aware that future versions of .net would support interface covariance and contravariance, it would have been possible and useful to split the interface into `IReadableList<out T>`, `IAppendable<in T>`, and `IList<T>` which would inherit both of the above.  Doing so would have imposed a small amount of additional work on vb.net implementers (they would have to define both read-only and read-write versions of the indexed property, since for some reason .net doesn't allow a read-write property to do serve as a read-only property) but would mean that methods which simply need to read items from a list could receive an `IReadableList<T>` in covariant fashion, and methods which simply need a collection they can append to could receive an `IAppendable<T>` in contravariant fashion.

Unfortunately, the only way such a thing could be implemented today would be if Microsoft provided a means for new interfaces be substitutable for older ones, with implementations of the old interfaces automatically using default methods supplied by the new ones.  I would think such a feature (interface substitutability) would be extremely helpful, but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for Microsoft to implement it.

Given that there's no way to back-fit `IReadableList<T>` into `IList<T>`, an alternative approach would be to define one's own list-related interface.  The one difficulty with doing so is that all instances of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` would have to be replaced with some other type, though the difficulty of doing that could be minimized if one were to define a `List<T>` struct in a different namespace which contained a single `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` field and defined widening conversions to and from the system type (using a struct rather than a class would mean that code would avoid the need to create new heap objects when casting in any scenario where the struct wouldn't have to be boxed).

Comment: I would be very wary of redefining something as basic as List<T>; the chances of someone getting confused are around 100%, I suspect.