# How to cast object at runtime, while getting type information at runtime

Tags: c#

Please have a look at below code.
Issue is at following loc.
MyClassExample obj2 = lstObjectCollection[0] as type;

I want to type cast an object of list to its type. But type will be given at runtime.

How can we cast an object, knowing its type at runtime?

```
class RTTIClass
{
    public void creatClass()
    {
        // Orignal object
        MyClassExample obj1 = new MyClassExample {NUMBER1 =5 };

        // Saving type of original object.
        Type type = typeof(MyClassExample);

        // Creating a list.
        List<object> lstObjectCollection = new List<object>();

        // Saving new object to list.
        lstObjectCollection.Add(CreateDuplicateObject(obj1));

        // Trying to cast saved object to its type.. But i want to check its RTTI with type and not by tightly coupled classname.
        // How can we achive this.
        MyClassExample obj2 = lstObjectCollection[0] as type;           
    }


    public object CreateDuplicateObject(object originalObject)
    {
        //create new instance of the object
        object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(originalObject.GetType());

        //get list of all properties
        var properties = originalObject.GetType().GetProperties();

        //loop through each property
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            //set the value for property
            property.SetValue(newObject, property.GetValue(originalObject, null), null);
        }


        //get list of all fields
        var fields = originalObject.GetType().GetFields();

        //loop through each field
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            //set the value for field
            field.SetValue(newObject, field.GetValue(originalObject));
        }

        // return the newly created object with all the properties and fields values copied from original object
        return newObject;
    } 

}


class MyClassExample
{

    public int NUMBER1 {get; set;}
    public int NUMBER2{get; set;}
    public int number3;
    public int number4;
}
```

Comment: Check if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312858/how-can-i-convert-types-at-runtime

Comment: Your example is confusing.  If you don't know what type to assign obj2, what can you do with that reference?  In other words, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: By confusing I mean - is CreateDuplicateObject at all relevant?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I normally use is the `is` operator which will tell whether your object is a particular type.  This will work if you already kinda sorta know which objects you will be using

```
Object myObject

if(myObject is Obj1)
    // do obj1 stuff
else if(myObject is Obj2)
    // do stuff with obj2
```

I've never had it come up where i had to operate on more than a handful of different types and treat them all specially, so this is what i normally do.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get all the objects of a certain type in the list using the `OfType<T>` extension method:

```
lstObjectCollection.OfType<MyClassExample>()
```

If the type is only known at runtime, you can do this:

```
lstObjectCollection.Where(o => o.GetType() == type)
```

Comment: Type of MyClassExample class is in type object. At runtime, i am not sure which class will be in type object. type in which the object will be casted will be found at runtime.