# converting string to?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I'm working on building a dynamic calculation framework, that will build a generic GUI based on the calculation types and attributes on those types.

For instance, I might have a simple Adder calculator (forgive the simplicity, but when putting together frameworks, I like to start simple and work my way up), that looks like this:

```
[CalculatorAttribute("This calculator add X+Y=Z")]
class AdderCalculator : CalculatorBase
{
    [CalculationValueAttribute(InputOutputEnum.InputValue, "First Input")]
    public int? X 
    {
        set { m_X = value; m_Z = null;}
        get { return m_X; }
    }

    [CalculationValueAttribute(InputOutputEnum.InputValue, "Second Input")]
    public int? Y 
    {
        set{ m_Y = value; m_Z = null;}
        get { return m_Y; }
    }

    [CalculationValueAttribute(InputOutputEnum.OutputValue, "Output")]
    public int? Z 
    {
        get { return m_Z; }
    }

    public AdderCalculator()
    {
        m_X = m_Y = m_Z = null;
    }

    public override Boolean ReadyToCalc()
    {
        return (m_X != null && m_Y != null);
    }

    public override Boolean NeedToCalc()
    {
        return (m_Z == null);
    }

    public override void Calculate()
    {
        if(ReadyToCalc()){ m_Z = m_X + m_Y;}
    }

    private int? m_X, m_Y, m_Z;
}
```

(forgive the whitespace, I tried to reduce the size as much as possible without sacrificing too much readability).

I'm using the nullable type to allow me to distinguish unset values from set values

Now, in my GUI, I'm using `TextBox`es to collect the input information. From `TextBox`, I can only get the Text (String). Using reflection, I know the name of the property and can get it's setter (`set_X` or `set_Y` in this case).

The type of the field is (of course) `int?` (nullable int), but I can use:

```
 PropertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
```

method to get the `Int32` type (or `Int64`, whichever may be the case).

So, given that I can end up with a instance of a `Type` object, can anyone recommend a generic way to convert `String` to that type

What I have considered is:

1. Implement a string setter method in my AdderCalculator: `set_X(String s)`
2. Change my control type to `NumericUpDown`, as it will return a `Decimal`
3. change the type to `Decimal`, but `Decimal` can't directly convert from `String` either (it can use parse, but that is tougher from a generic standpoint

Can anyone provide additional insight?

Comment: See if any of the answers to [this question][1] are helpful?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312858/how-can-i-convert-types-at-runtime

Comment: @nikeaa - thanks, looks like the 'object o = Convert.ChangeType(c.Text, ti);' will work for what I need. Still need to be careful and handle exceptions. I swear I searched for an hour on how to do it, I guess my search was too narrow...appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get the answer out where it can be clearly seen, the code I ended up with is:

```
            // collect relevant inputs
            foreach (Control c in fPanelIn.Controls)
            {
                if (c.Tag is PropertyInfo) 
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = c.Tag as PropertyInfo;

                    if(c.Text.Length>0)
                    {
                        Type ti = pi.PropertyType;

                        if (ti.IsGenericType)
                        {
                            ti = ti.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        }
                        object o = Convert.ChangeType(c.Text, ti);

                        pi.SetValue(Calculator, o, null);

                        //MethodInfo mi = calcType.GetMethod(ConstructMethodName(pi), new Type[] { typeof(String) });

                        //mi.Invoke(Calculator, new object[] { c.Text });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(Calculator, null, null);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I still need to add some exception protection for invalid values, but this works with the property type being any numeric type (byte, short, int, int32, int64, float, double, Decimal, etc...)