# Change Type of Object to its SubType and Return it

Tags: c#, object, casting, return

I have a method that returns an `Object` of some type.  On the receiving end, I want this object to be cast as the type it is without casting it.  I can do this:

```
public static Object Method1(){
return GetObjectOfSomeType();
}

public static void Method2(){
MethodThatTakesBool((bool) Method1());
}
```

But I have a lot of methods similar to `Method2`, and I wanted to avoid having to cast it every time.  (It is not always a `bool`...it is a different type every time.)  What I would like to do is this:

```
public static Object Method1(){
return (GetType()) GetObjectOfSomeType();
}

public static void Method2(){
MethodThatTakesBool(Method1());
}
```

How can I cast an object as itself, then have that object returned as that type?  I tried this, but it does not work:

```
return (myObject.GetType().ToString()) myObject;
```

Comment: Sounds like what you want is generics. But your question is not clear enough to be sure.

Comment: How can I clear it up?

Comment: Looks like @das has you covered.  You are in good hands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that it does not make sense to cast an object unless you know the desired type of the cast at compile time (i.e. "the static type").

However, you could make a generic method that hides the cast. It is entirely equivalent to having the cast in the calling code, but it looks like a method call, not a cast:

```
static T Method1<T>() {
    object res =  GetObjectOfSomeType();
    return (T)res;
}
```

Here is how to use this method:

```
public static void Method2(){
    MethodThatTakesBool(Method1<bool>());
    MethodThatTakesInt(Method1<int>());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does look nicer. I think I may use it :) And as for your concerns about not making sense, I am just trying to make a helper method for some Windows API (Loading Data)

Comment: Darn! cannot return null in this method!  ---   Nevermind! Jon Skeet to the rescue again!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302096/how-can-i-return-null-from-a-generic-method-in-c

Comment: _"The first thing to note is that it does not make sense to cast an object unless you know the desired type of the cast at compile time"_ Hmm... Would it mean that casts do not make sense for scripting languages which have no concept of compile-time at all :-)?

Comment: @AlexD Of course all this is said in the context of C#. For scripting languages that would the the "translation time" - i.e. the time when the interpreter is making sense of the program.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Maybe it is too theoretical, but I'd say there are cases where it makes sense to cast to a type known at run-time only. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/312898.